# Disable the payment options on klarna payment page

Tags: payment-method, klarna, klarna-widget

i want to show only specific payment option on klarna payment page. in my case it show to payment option 1) pay now and 2) pay in 30 days. i want that user should not able select pay now option.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oKVv.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot deactivate Klarna Checkout payment methods yourself. If you have a contract with Klarna then you should contact merchant support.
We had the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can set the payment methods on widget load, but you have to make sure that the method is available from the session call.

```
Klarna.Payments.load({
        container: '#klarna_container',
            payment_method_category: 'pay_later'
            
        }
```